# How to add two minipage in latex document

Tags: minipage

I need to add two minipage of different sizes. One is about 2inch in width and other is till the margin in the same line.[image]
Like this pic...

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Not very clear. What is *adding* two minipages?

Comment: Seemingly related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/330139/how-can-i-make-table-like-this-in-latex

Comment: Please do not ask the same question multiple times. Have you read the instructions liked in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/330139/how-can-i-make-table-like-this-in-latex#comment808959_330139 ?

Comment: If you are writing an article for a journal, follow the instructions they provide and do not try to replicate the layout on your own. They have templates for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a method using `tabularx` for the general layout, with the letterspacing in the headers made with `microtype`. 
I'm not really sure if you really want ot have the top line there, but if you don't just remove the `\hline\\`

#### Output

[image]

#### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[letterspace=150]{microtype}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\hf}[1]{%Header Formate
  {\scshape\lsstyle#1}%
}
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}p{3.5cm}X@{}}
  \hline\\
  \hf{article info} & \hf{abstract}\\[-2ex]
   \hrule & \hrule\\[-2ex]
  Keywords:

  Monge's method

  Intermediate integrals &
     In this paper we will present a framework of solving a second order differential equation using a solvable first order equation. Such a first order equation is called an intermediate integral. Illustrative examples are used to highlight the proposed algorithm.

     \hfill\copyright{} 2010 Elsevier Inc. All Rights Reserved.
     \\[-2ex]
    \hrule & \hrule\\[-2ex]
\end{tabularx}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this:

[image]

### Notes:

- [The `showframe` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/showframe)
  was used just to show the page margins.
  It is not needed in your actual use case.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newcommand*{\LeftMiniPageLength}{2.0in}
\newcommand*{\MinipageSep}{0.1in}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\LeftMiniPageLength}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}%
\hspace*{\MinipageSep}%
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-\LeftMiniPageLength-\MinipageSep\relax}
    \lipsum[3]
\end{minipage}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Want little part of minipage from whole page. May to write two to three lines.

Comment: @M.Affan: The solution above can be used for any amopunt of text (as long as it fits on a single page), so not sure why you think that wrtiting just two or three lines is a problem.  If this does not work for you, I suggest you edit the question to include a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that reproduces the problem.  Without this it is going to be difficlut to help you further.

Comment: @PeterGrill Please have a look at the relate question (link in comment section to the question) for referencce.

Comment: See pic in question added after editing

Comment: @M.Affan: I asumed that since you had already posted [How can I make table like this in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/330139/how-can-i-make-table-like-this-in-latex) that this was a different question about two minipages -- not a specfic case of horizontal rules.  But, you can still put both pices of text in the solution I provided, so I belive it answers your original question.